# SVG's appear black on MS Edge

Tags: html, css, svg

Somehow my images are shown perfectly on chrome and firefox, but on MS Edge it appears to be black. I surround my svg files with a html file so I can load them in another html file. Is this a known-issue? And does somebody have a solution?

**Example:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIBGk.jpg

The code structure looks like this:

```
<template style="display: flex">
<svg class="svgclassname" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
<--Styling and paths-->
</svg>
</template>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the full src of your svg?

Comment: You should not put a `style` on a native HTML `template` tag (I say native, as other node-based XML systems might define their own template tags, so I can't be 100% sure). Otherwise it doesnt hurt to include the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` attribute and a `width` and `height` (defined in an absolute unit like `px`) for compatibility.

Comment: Your usage pattern looks suspiciously like a [SVG sprite](https://24ways.org/2014/an-overview-of-svg-sprite-creation-techniques/). Instead of using a `<template>` element, you should make yourself familiar with SVG's own templating mechanism with [`<symbol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol) and [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use).

Comment: Thank you all for the reactions. I am not possible to upload the full source of the svg files due to security reasons. However, do u think I should solve this issue within the svg file? Since I want to style the svg's after specific actions (for example if someone clicks a button --> svg has to be gray). I thought it was only possible if I surround it with a html file. For this project I am using CSS HTML Typescript and Aurelia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason MS Edge ignored my styling WITHIN the svg file. Calling fill on the paths fixed my issue.

Comment: This appears to be the same as the issue I have, but what do you mean by "calling fill on the paths"?
Do you mean change: ```style="fill:#f18703"``` to ```fill="#f18703"```

Answer (score 1):

If you surround your SVG with HTML and wish to use them in another HTML file, you can include them as images, instead.

```
<img src="mysvg.svg"/>
```

If you want to change `fill`, `stroke` or some other property, you will need to do that for that from the main SVG file.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am surrounding this svg with a html file so I indeed have access to the classes. It must be possible to make these svg's gray and back to their normal color. That is why I choose to surround it with a html file.